# Getting input values from text box

Tags: javascript, html, input, textbox

I'm trying to get the text from a text box.

I have 2 input text boxes that are not in a form, and I'm trying to retrieve the `value` and store it in a variable.

This code returns `undefined` in the alert box that pops up.

```
<script>
    var userPass = document.getElementById('pass');
    var userName = document.getElementById('fName');
    function submit(){
        alert(userPass.value);
    }
</script>
```

When I run it with `userName.value` as a parameter in the alert function, it will work and display what ever you type in the box.

Here is the html:

```
 <table id="login">
        <tr>
            <td><label>User Name</label></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><input class="textBox" id="fName" type="text" maxlength="30"    required/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td id="pass"><label>Password</label></td>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><input class="textBox" id="pass" type="text" maxlength="30" required/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="button" class="loginButtons" value="Login" onclick="submit();"/>&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
            <input type="button" class="loginButtons" value="Cancel"/></td>
    </table>
```

Comment: <input class="textBox" id="pass" type="text" maxlength="30" required/>

Comment: I disagree with Matthew. Keep doing what you're doing, and learn the basics. Seems that a number of jQuery users have skipped this step. Then when you've got a solid foundation, you may or may not decide to use one of the many JavaScript libraries out there.

Comment: I figured it out had and id named pass on accident. Thank you all

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will notice you have no value attr in the `input` tags.
Also, although not shown, make sure the Javascript is run **after** the html is in place.

Comment: Should I have a default value in my input element?

Comment: try it, I would assume each browser is a bit different in this regard.

Answer (score 6):

```
<script>
  function submit(){
      var userPass = document.getElementById('pass');
      var userName = document.getElementById('user');
      alert(user.value);
      alert(pass.value);
  }
</script>
```

```
<input type="text" id="user" />
<input type="text" id="pass" />
<button onclick="submit();" href="javascript:;">Submit</button>
```

Answer (score 5):

// NOTE: Using "this.pass" and "this.name" will create a global variable even though it is inside the function, so be weary of your naming convention

```
function submit()
{
    var userPass = document.getElementById("pass").value;
    var userName = document.getElementById("user").value;
    this.pass = userPass;
    this.name = userName; 
    alert("whatever you want to display"); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

you have multiple elements with the same id.  That is a big no-no. Make sure your inputs have **unique** ids.

```
<td id="pass"><label>Password</label></td>
<tr>
   <td colspan="2"><input class="textBox" id="pass" type="text" maxlength="30" required/></td>
</tr>
```

see, both the `td` and the `input` share the id value `pass`.

Comment: Yea I seen that thank you. I didn't even realize I named the <td> that. Appreciate the help

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `id="pass"` off the `td` element. Right now the js will get the td element instead of the input hence the value is undefined.

Comment: Thank you that's wat it was. Appreciate the help

Answer (score 1):

Javascript document.getElementById("<%=contrilid.ClientID%>").value; or using jquery

$("#<%= txt_iplength.ClientID %>").val();

Answer (score 0):

This is the sample code for the email and javascript.

```
params = getParams();
subject = "ULM Query of: ";
subject += unescape(params["FormsEditField3"]);
content = "Email: ";
content += unescape(params["FormsMultiLine2"]);
content += "      Query:    ";
content += unescape(params["FormsMultiLine4"]);
var email = "ni@gmail.com";
document.write('<a href="mailto:'+email+'?subject='+subject+'&body='+content+'">SUBMIT QUERY</a>');
```